# Problems with a regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, encoding, character-encoding

I have a `very_largeString` that contains a list of words and and some id. I would like to extract all the words (with their ids) that have `RG` and `AQ` that morphologically occur  consecutively and print the rest of the id. The output is just the word and its associated id for example: `[('word','id'),('word','id')]`

```
very_largeString= ''' Hola hola I 1
compis compis NCMS000 0.500006
! ! Fat 1

No no RN 0.998045
sabía saber VMII3S0 0.592869
como como CS 0.999289
se se P00CN000 0.465639
ponía poner VMII3S0 0.65
una uno DI0FS0 0.951575
lavadora lavadora NCFS000 0.414738
hasta hasta SPS00 0.957698
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
conocí conocer VMIS1S0 1
esta este DD0FS0 0.986779
y y CC 0.999962
muy muy RG 1
sencilla malo AQ0MP0
es ser VSIP3S0 1
que que CS 0.437483
es ser VSIP3S0 1
muy muy RG 1
sencilla sencillo AQ0FS0 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
utilizar utilizar VMN0000 1
! ! Fat 1    
'''
```

This will be the desired output, since they have at the beggining of the id the RG and AQ characters, then i want to return the full id e.g.:

```
[('muy', RG), ('sencillo', 'AQ0FS0'),('muy'),('malo','AQ0MP0')]
```

The problem is that I'm obtaining a null output. This is what i tried:

```
result = re.findall("(\S+)\s+(RG\S+).*\n.*\s(\S+)\s+(AQ\S+)",very_largeString)
```

Could anybody help me to fix this regex?, I don't know why it´s wrong.

Comment: Do you have to use a regex? I would probably just split the string into lines and just work from there.

Comment: what output do you want exactly?

Comment: Python regular expressions don't span multiple lines by default. You need to set the [re.DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) setting in findall

Comment: @sirlark: I don't think he wants `.` to match newlines; he's trying to find cases where the two lines are continuous, so there should be exactly one `\n` between them, the one he's matching explicitly.

Comment: @abarnert right you are, I misread the question

Comment: I put the output in the question `[('muy', RG), ('sencillo', 'AQ0FS0'),('muy'),('malo','AQ0MP0')]`

Comment: I want to find cases where RG and AQ ocurre one after the other for example, from : `muy muy RG 1
sencilla sencillo AQ0FS0 1`

Comment: why i have negative score in this question?

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that `RG\S+` isn't going to match `RG 1`, because that space doesn't match one or more non-space characters. I think you wanted `\s+` there? (Or maybe `\S*`? But I don't see any `RG1`-type possible matches. Or maybe nothing at all, because I'm not sure what any sub-pattern is attempting to do here?)

```
(\S+)\s+(RG\s+).\n.*\s(\S+)\s+(AQ\S+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Y5mPwjxVFVyopSIm)

However, that doesn't give you the desired output. What it gives you is this:

```
[('muy', 'RG ', 'malo', 'AQ0MP0'), ('muy', 'RG ', 'sencillo', 'AQ0FS0')]
```

The `'RG '` is pretty obvious—you're trying to match *something* mandatory after `RG`, and the only thing that ever comes after `RG` is a space, so what else could you possibly get`?

You also seem to want to match the first and second lines separately—which is doable, but only with a horrendously complicated expression with lookaheads and lookbehinds, and a lot simpler to just post-process the list.

You also seem to want the pairs in reverse order. I suppose that might be possible in theory, but I have absolutely no idea how you'd even begin to do that, and I suspect anything that worked would take exponential time—again, much simpler to do by post-processing.

And finally, for some reason, you want the second pair to match just `('muy')` rather than `('muy', 'RG')`, which (a) doesn't make any sense, because `('muy')` is not a 1-item tuple, it's just the string `'muy'`, and (b) I have no idea how you'd expect to match two things the first time but only one thing with the exact same pattern and the same line the second time.

Assuming most of your requirements are actually not real, and the only thing you want to do is regroup them from 4s into 2s, like this:

```
[('muy', 'RG'), ('malo', 'AQ0MP0'), ('muy', 'RG'), ('sencillo', 'AQ0FS0')]
```

… I'd move the `\s+` out of the regex, and post-process the results from groups of 4 into groups of 2, like this:

```
result = re.findall(r"(\S+)\s+(RG)\s+.*\n.*\s(\S+)\s+(AQ\S+)",very_largeString)
flattened = (x for y in result for x in y)
paired = list(zip(flattened, flattened))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tweak it, something like this
`(\S+)\s+(RG\S*).*\n.*[^\S\n](\S+)[^\S\n]+(AQ\S*)`
will kind of get what your expected output is.

```
 ( \S+ )          # (1)
 \s+ 
 ( RG \S* )       # (2)
 .* \n 
 .* [^\S\n] 
 ( \S+ )          # (3)
 [^\S\n]+ 
 ( AQ \S* )       # (4)
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 358 , len 29 ) 
muy RG 1
sencilla malo AQ0MP0  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 358 , len 3 ) 
muy  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 362 , len 2 ) 
RG  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 376 , len 4 ) 
malo  
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 381 , len 6 ) 
AQ0MP0  

------------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 446 , len 33 ) 
muy RG 1
sencilla sencillo AQ0FS0  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 446 , len 3 ) 
muy  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 450 , len 2 ) 
RG  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 464 , len 8 ) 
sencillo  
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 473 , len 6 ) 
AQ0FS0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this

```
 re.findall('(\w+\s+)(RG\w*|AQ\w*)',very_largeString)
```

output:

```
[('muy ', 'RG'), ('malo ', 'AQ0MP0'), ('muy ', 'RG'), ('sencillo ', 'AQ0FS0')]
```

if you want to remove duplication you can use `set`

Comment: For some reason, the OP seems to want 2 pairs on adjacent lines. Either way, its the same question asked but a different week. I first noticed the question about a month ago, different users.

Comment: I want to generate a bigram

Comment: maybe regex are not the correct aproach for this task, what other aproach can i use?. Just split the string into lines could be better?